# CloudSQL Programming Language Support

Tags: google-cloud-platform, configuration, google-cloud-sql

I was told by a third-party vendor that Python, JavaScript, and potentially other programming languages cannot be installed on CloudSQL. I am trying to verify if this is true, and if so, why is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

CloudSQL is a service that provides database as a service for you. It is not a generic purpose VPS server where you can install anything.

If you want to use programming languages, then you need a separate VPS where you install the software. You can use the CloudSQL service from your VPS.